# Re-trigger scheduled instances with SAP BO API?

Tags: jar, sdk, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I want to re-trigger all the failed schedules using a java jar file on CMS.

Just for testing I wrote this below program which I suppose would re-trigger a certain schedule, which completed successfully.

Please help me find where did I go wrong since it shows success when I run this program on CMS but the schedule doesn't get triggered

```
public class Schedule_CRNA implements IProgramBase {
 public void run(IEnterpriseSession enterprisesession, IInfoStore infostore, String str[]) throws SDKException {
  //System.out.println("Connected to " + enterprisesession.getCMSName() + "CMS");
  //System.out.println("Using the credentials of " + enterprisesession.getUserInfo().getUserName() );
  IInfoObjects oInfoObjects = infostore.query("SELECT * from CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE si_instance=1 and si_schedule_status=1 and SI_ID=9411899");
  for (int x = 0; x < oInfoObjects.size(); x++) {
   IInfoObject oI = (IInfoObject) oInfoObjects.get(x);
   IInfoObjects oScheds = infostore.query("select * from ci_infoobjects,ci_appobjects where si_id = " + oI.getID());
   IInfoObject oSched = (IInfoObject) oScheds.get(0);

   Integer iOwner = (Integer) oI.properties().getProperty("SI_OWNERID").getValue();

   oSched.getSchedulingInfo().setScheduleOnBehalfOf(iOwner);
   oSched.getSchedulingInfo().setRightNow(true);
   oSched.getSchedulingInfo().setType(CeScheduleType.ONCE);
   infostore.schedule(oScheds);
   oI.deleteNow();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the putting of your retrieved scheduled object into collection.

The last part in your snippet should be:

```
oSched.getSchedulingInfo().setScheduleOnBehalfOf(iOwner);
oSched.getSchedulingInfo().setRightNow(true);
oSched.getSchedulingInfo().setType(CeScheduleType.ONCE);
IInfoObjects objectsToSchedule = infostore.newInfoObjectCollection();
objectsToSchedule.add(oI);
infostore.schedule(objectsToSchedule);
oI.deleteNow();
```

You cannot schedule report directly but rather through collection. Full sample [is here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0225aa3e7b4b4b17b2d4a882e6f2de96/4.2.4/en-US/45a67f296e041014910aba7db0e91070.html).

Also your coding deleting object from repository and rescheduling it again with each iteration seems weird, but it is up to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks but my original code worked and it re-triggered the schedule. Upon checking the txt file in the output FRS logs i found that there was jre version mismatch. SO i re-build the jar with 1.6 version and it worked. PFFFT should have checked this first!!!